# Get all sockets in a room with nestJS

Tags: sockets, socket.io, nestjs

What is the best way to get all connected sockets in a selected room. I've found this line :

```
io.in(roomID).fetchSockets()
```

But in my nestJS structure I don't have an IO instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use decorator provided by NestJS. Nest will automatically assign the server instance to this property once it is ready to use.

```
@WebSocketServer()
server: Server;
```

Somewhere before constructor and other methods together with other service/class properties. Then you could use it like this: `this.server.in(roomID).fetchSockets();`